# To refute : a function with one discontinuity point is integrable on $\left[0, 1\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If, let $f: \left[ 0, 1\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous with only one discontinuity point is integrable on $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

---

I think this is **false** but I can't find a example that contradicts the statement.

Comment: Was there any mention as to whether the function is assumed to be bounded?

Comment: Wouldn't it be true? If f is a part of real space from [0, 1] than you couldn't have a value which was not in real space, which is irrational, rational, integers, etc. numbers. You are saying it is continuous from [0, 1], and you are integrating it on [0, 1], and a property of integrals is if it is continuous on an interval you can integrate it on that interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:[0\,,1]\to\Bbb R$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\in (0\,,1]$. The integral diverges, because $\ln |x|\to-\infty$ as $x\to0$. For an example not involving the logarithm, replace $1/x$ by $1/x^2$; the integral diverges in this case because $1/x\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Remember me why this function isn't integrable. By Darboux?

Comment: @hlapointe: I expanded my answer; I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks you.

Comment: If I have to prove it, should I use the Darboux integral?

Comment: @hlapointe: The integral is not definable (i.e. it diverges)  whatever definition of integration one uses: put simply, the area bounded by the hyperbola $xy=1$ and the $x$ and $y$ axes is not defined (it is infinite).

Comment: For most presentations of the Riemann and improper Riemann integrals one defines such an integral as $$\int_0^1 \frac1x \,dx= \lim_{t\to0+} \int_t^1 \frac1x \,dx$$ and the understanding is that the integral $\int_t^1$ on the right exists (since $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is continuous on $[t,1]$) but that the limit fails to exist.  That may seem overly pedantic but on first learning such a subject it is best to rely on definitions until your intuition develops. [Since this function is unbounded on $[0,1]$ there is no Riemann or Darboux integral possible, only this "improper" one.]

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: Your improper integral is not defined, because the limit does not exist. I don't see what point you are making here.

Comment: The point is that this is the actual definition.  The fact that the limit fails to exist is your proof that the improper Riemann integral does not exist. (This is implicit in what you did, but not completely transparent for the poster.)  If you wish to prove this function does not have a Lebesgue integral (among others) you would have to come up with a different proof.  If you wish to prove that the function is not Riemann integrable, you would claim that it is unbounded and hence not Riemann integrable.